# How do I open a JFrame from another class?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, stack-overflow

So i need to open a JFrame in a "Window" class using a "Louncher" class.
It doesn't work, i am not sure why since im really new to java.

So this is the Louncher:

```
package struktogrammer;

public class Louncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Window feld = new Window();

    }

}
```

This is the Window:

```
package struktogrammer;


import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private int width = 1000;
    private int hight = 750;

    public Window() {

        Window frame = new Window();

        frame.setTitle("Struktogramm");
        frame.setSize(width, hight);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public Window(int width, int hight) {

        this.width = width;
        this.hight = hight;

        Window frame = new Window();

        frame.setTitle("Struktogramm");
        frame.setSize(width, hight);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When running the Louncher class i get like 5 pages of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at struktogrammer.Window.<init>(Window.java:15)
    at struktogrammer.Window.<init>(Window.java:17)
    ... (same lign about 1200 times)
    at struktogrammer.Window.<init>(Window.java:17)
```

It seams that i run an infinite loop, since it can't use the constructor?
Pleas help!

Comment: `public Window() {

        Window frame = new Window();`  This will cause an infinite loop.  Do you know why?

Comment: Oh, wow... i feel a tad bit retarded now :D

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the **both** constructors make the same mistake.  ;)

Comment: Tip:  rather than `addWindowListener(..` use `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` or (I prefer) `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a new window, another window is created... infinitely. You need to remove the creation of another Window object in the constructor for the Window object.

```
 public Window() {

    // Window frame = new Window(); <---Remove this

    frame.setTitle("Struktogramm");
    frame.setSize(width, hight);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Window class, you are creating again window class frames:

```
 Window frame = new Window();
```

Since you don't need to create a frame inside this class every time you call the method, remove it. You are creating a frame every time you create a frame.. infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a JFrame and add a JButton in it than add action listener in button and add this code in it like this:

This code makes a frame with a button and when button is pressed new window is opened.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

public Example() {
    super("Title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton b = new JButton("Open new Frame");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            newWindow nw = new newWindow();

        }
    });

    add(b);

  } 
 }
```

newWindow Code:

```
public class newWindow extends JFrame {

newWindow() {
    super("title");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true);
 }  
}
```